# How to disable the welcome message from neo4j?

Tags: html, neo4j

I'm using a web page to show neo4j server in a framework. I want to know how to disable the two welcome messages from opening when this page is loaded or when neo4j is logged in. the screenshot is below.

[image: This image contains the welcome message window after login]

Answer (score 1):

By default the initial command that runs when you open Neo4j Browser is `:play start` which shows the "welcome message" guide. You can configure this initial command by clicking on the settings icon and changing the setting `Initial Command`. If you leave this field blank then no browser guide will play on startup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks You for the reply.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the " :server connect"  from starting screen which shows the http://host:port/browser

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an answer pane by clicking on the "X" button on its top right hand corner.